# Casting a generic List to a subtype (unsafe contravariance)

Tags: java, generics, covariance

Assuming I have a `List<Base>` that I know contains only elements of type `Derived`, how can I force a cast to a `List<Derived>`?

Comment: Make it raw and cast back. Smells though.

Comment: As a one-liner `List<Derived> deriveds = (List<Derived>)(List)bases;`, but indeed, this sounds like a questionable design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
  public static <T> List<T>
cast(List<? super T> list, Class<T> clazz) {

        if( list.stream().allMatch( clazz::isInstance ) )
            return (List<T>) list;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Not all inputs are of class " + clazz.getName());
    }
```

Comment: You could use `List<? super T>` to prevent someone trying to call `List<String> s = cast(myNumbers, String.class)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Number> foo = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Integer> a = cast(foo);

    System.out.println("a = " + a);
}

public static <T, C extends T> List<C> cast( List<T> l ) {
    return (List<C>) l;
}
```